How do I implement a program in shell to display the list of users connected to the system and all the processes launched by that user?
Write a Shell program that supervises the system, such that: for each new connection in the system, on the terminal from which the connection was made, it will print a list of all active users from the system, and for each user it will print the number of launched processes by that user.
I tried to create a shell script and iterate through the users, but it doesn't display me anything when I execute the script. Here is what I have written:
users=$(who | awk '{print $1}')
for user in $users; do
    nrprocesses=$(ps -u $user | wc -l)
    echo "User: $user, number of processes: $nrprocesses"
done


Is this a homework assignment? Why did you tag this PowerShell?

Yes, it is a homework assignment and I have to user PowerShell to solve it.

You are missing a dollar sign at the beginning : $users = $(who | awk '{print $1}')  also a dollar sign in the for loop : for $user in $users;
